# How to install Sencha Ext JS 6?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I've stopped on the third step of the official [instruction](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/getting_started/getting_started.html).

In terminal I enter sencha and there's a message: No such file or directory
What folders should I create, which directory should be current when I enter command? Could you explain the 3rd step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 3 command reads -

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/extjs/framework generate app AppName path/to/app

cd /path/to/app

sencha app watch
```

There are 3 commands here-

The first command creates an app.

The second command tells you to browse to the project  folder you just created.

And the third command basically starts an http server and hosts your app on that server so that you can access your app.

Let me explain the first command to you:

`sencha -sdk /path/to/extjs/framework generate app AppName path/to/app`

**/path/to/extjs/framework** - in step 2 you must have unzipped the sdk folder somewhere. You need to specify path to that folder here

**AppName** - the name you want to assign to your project.can be anything

**path/to/app** - location path where you want to create your application.

Comment: Thank you, Manish! Now it works! 
"/path/to/extjs/framework - in step 2 you must have unzipped the sdk folder somewhere" - I couldn't understand what is folder "framework", because unzipped folder is called ext-6.0.1)